# Fuzzywuzzy has no attribute 'extractone'

Tags: python, fuzzywuzzy

I have a dataframe as:

```
alertname   custname
0   wlison  wilson
1   dais    said
2   4dams   adams
3   ad4ms   adams
4   ad48s   adams
5   smyth   smith
6   smythe  smith
7   gillan  gillan
8   gilen   gillan
9   scott-smith scottsmith
10  scott smith scottsmith
11  perrson person
12  persson person
```

Now when I run the following command from `fuzzywuzzy` package:

```
from fuzzywuzzy import process
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import Levenshtein

key=['wilson']


process.extractone(key, choices=alertname,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,limit=10)
```

It gives me the following error:

`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'extractone'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its

```
process.extractOne(key, choices=alertname,scorer=fuzz.token_sort_ratio,limit=10)
```

you missed to captalize O

Comment: Thanks Kalyan. Silly mistake. Mind was occupied in multiple stuff.